# getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK exception when connectig Redis server

Tags: java, exception, nosuchmethoderror

I'm getting a `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK` exception when connecting redis server. I have removed actual host and port details in the code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.connectionBuilder(AbstractRedisClient.java:148)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connectStatefulAsync(RedisClient.java:303)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connectStandaloneAsync(RedisClient.java:271)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:204)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:189)
    at testpack.RedisClientTest.setCacheIntoRedis(RedisClientTest.java:30)
    at testpack.RedisClientTest.main(RedisClientTest.java:24)
```

The code:

```
public class RedisClientTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setCacheIntoRedis("TestKey", "Hello Redis");

    }

    public static void setCacheIntoRedis(String key, String value) {
        // Removed actual server details
        RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create("redis://redis123@host:port/0");
        StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection = redisClient.connect();
        RedisCommands<String, String> syncCommands = connection.sync();

        syncCommands.set(key, value);

        connection.close();
        redisClient.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Comment: It's probably a conflict with your netty version. can you please provide your pom.xml

Comment: This is just a standalone program. I'm using below jars.
=====================================================
lettuce-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar
netty-all-4.0.0.CR1.jar
netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar
netty-handler-4.1.36.Final.jar
netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar
reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar
reactor-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Did you tried to use 4.1.36 for netty-all ?

Comment: Thank you. It worked with netty-all-4.1.36.Final.jar

Answer (score 0):

You're having a conflict due to different versions of netty dependencies. Lettuce 5.1.7 actually dependes on netty 4.1.36 there for you should use netty-all 4.1.36 instead of 4.0.0.